# unisharp filemanager changes original images size after upload

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, upload, file-manager

Hi I'm using [uniSharp](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager)  filemanager but I have a problem!

When I upload an image with 81 kb size the uploaded image size **increases** to **255** kb or more! which is really bad

How could I prevent such behavior ?

Any help would be appreciated.